# How to get value of Itemrenderer

Tags: flex4, checkbox, itemrenderer

I want to get value of checkbox from the itemrenderer.I have a datagrid with a checkBox as itemrenderer as follows:

```
<s:DataGrid id="myGrid" dataProvider="{module_DP}" rowHeight="35" fontSize="9"  
                    x="20" y="20" width="184" height="306">
            <s:columns>
                <s:ArrayList>                     
                    <s:GridColumn headerText="Access" dataField="access">
                        <s:itemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>
                                <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                    <s:CheckBox label="" click="Check_Click(event)" selected="@{data.access}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                                </s:GridItemRenderer>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </s:itemRenderer>
                    </s:GridColumn>
                </s:ArrayList>
            </s:columns>
        </s:DataGrid>
```

The Check_Click() method:

```
public function Check_Click():void{
trace(I want to get the value of clicked checkbox..in this case "access")
}
```

I cant figure out the code that I need to put in the trace.
   Can someone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
<s:CheckBox label="" click="Check_Click(event)" selected="@{data.access}" horizontalCenter="0"/>


public function Check_Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
   var cb:Checkbox = event.target as CheckBox
   trace(cb.selected);
}
```

The post title was asking a slightly different question "How to get value of Itemrenderer". Access the data property within the renderer, like you do with {data.access}.

To access it from outside:

```
<fx:Script>
   <![CDATA[
      import mx.events.FlexEvent;

      import spark.components.gridClasses.IGridItemRenderer;
      private function onGridInitialize(event:FlexEvent):void
      {
         this.addEventListener('moduleItemChange', onModuleItemChange);
      }
      private function onModuleItemChange(event:Event):void
      {
         var item:IGridItemRenderer = event.target as IGridItemRenderer;
         if(!item || !item.data) { /* deal with this */ } 
         trace(item.data.access);            
      }
   ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:DataGrid id="myGrid" rowHeight="35" fontSize="9"  
         x="20" y="20" width="184" height="306" 
         initialize="onGridInitialize(event)">
   <s:dataProvider>
      <s:ArrayList>         
         <fx:Object   access="true"/>
         <fx:Object   access="false"/>
         <fx:Object   access="false"/>
         <fx:Object   access="true"/>
         <fx:Object   access="true"/>               
      </s:ArrayList>
   </s:dataProvider>
   <s:columns>
      <s:ArrayList>                     
         <s:GridColumn headerText="Access" dataField="access">
            <s:itemRenderer>
               <fx:Component>
                  <s:GridItemRenderer>
                     <fx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                           private function Check_Click(even:MouseEvent):void
                           {
                              dispatchEvent(new Event('moduleItemChange', true));
                           }                           
                        ]]>
                     </fx:Script>
                     <s:CheckBox label="" click="Check_Click(event)" selected="@{data.access}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
                  </s:GridItemRenderer>
               </fx:Component>
            </s:itemRenderer>
         </s:GridColumn>
      </s:ArrayList>
   </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

Comment: In fact my function is outside the fx:Script block of the itemRenderer. It is in the general fx:Script block of the whole application. And when I try it there..that is I access the data property..I get the error "Property data cannot be found"

Any suggestion?

Comment: This works like a charm. I was wondering how I do if I have 3 grids instead. All the grid follows the data structure of the data provider. Hence the function in the general fx:Script remains intact.

The only thing is that I have to repeat the Check_Click function in every itemRenderer in each grid. 

But thanks for the solution, this is the first time I am calling an outside function. Learn something new :)

Comment: With 3 different grids, different options. The best one, make your code more local. Don't bubble it up till the application level. Deal with it within the component that holds the datagrid. If you feel you can't then use different event names for each datagrid (moduleItemChange, thisItemChange, thatItemChange) or dispatch a custom event that olds custom data like the item context. On calling an outside function, when you use dispatchEvent, don't forget to set the bubble parameter to true (it is false by default). Thanks for accepting the answer :)